# squares that can be divided to two squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There are some squares like 169 that can be divided into two squares(16 and 9). I classify them into two groups:

A:squares that their rightmost number isn't 0(like 169 and 4225)

B:squares that their rightmost number is 0(like 100 and 400)

creating a B type is so easy(we just have to multiply a square by 100),so the problem is:

How to prove that there are an infinite number of A squares?

Comment: $10^na^2 + b^2$ is such a number whenever $b$ is an integer whose square has $n$ digits.

Comment: @rogerl then is that 10^na^2+b^2 a square?

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to type these things well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$10a^2+1=b^2$ is an example of Pell's equation that has infinitely many solutions.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

The first example is $361=19^2$.